# Can't implement activity scenario

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I found in Google Example instrumented test something like this:

```
@Before
public void launchActivity() {
  ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class);
}
```

But i can't implemented `ActivityScenario` in my project.
I should add something to gradle or what ?

If I past `import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;` no help, i have `test` red in AndroidStudio.

How to implement AndroidScenario ?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `androidx.test:core:<currentVersion>` dependency to your gradle.

Like `"androidx.test:core:1.0.0-beta02"` or whatever the current version is.

Comment: This doesn't fix the `launchActivity` issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the

`androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$testCoreVersion"`

dependency in your build.gradle file in order to resolve `ActivityScenario`.

Further information can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup#add-libraries